# Ubuntu Video Editing is TERRIBLY Slow. Any fix?

Tags: graphics, video-editor

I recently made the leap from Windows to Linux, and I'm enjoying my freedom thus far with Ubuntu 18.04. I've played quite a few games so far CS:GO, Minecraft with heavy shaders, Kenshi, ARK, etc. and I've had no performance issues.

However, one area I've found frustrating is video editing. I've tried Lightworks, Shotcut, and Openshot, and all have been ridiculously slow when performing simple actions. For example, zooming in and out on the timeline or splitting a video always causes a 2- to 5-second freeze, which gets VERY frustrating when editing.

I've been using the NVIDIA 430 proprietary drivers for my NVIDIA GTX 1050 ti, and they've worked perfectly for gaming. I've also tried using the 390 proprietary drivers, but these haven't made a difference to video editing performance.

I have 8 GB RAM total, and 2 GB of swap, as per `awk '/^(MemTotal|SwapTotal)/{print $2}' /proc/meminfo`.

Obviously, this could just be a problem with the video editors made for Linux, but I highly doubt it, considering that Lightworks is a professional-grade technology. Is there anything I can do to fix this?  How can I troubleshoot this?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver. Here are my results: 8094600
2097148